# rails touch chain with has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Using a join model, with a `has_many :through` on this example setup

```
class Collage
 has_many :arrangements
 has_many :photos, through: :arrangements

class Photo
 has_many :arragements
 has_many :collages, through: :arragements
end

class Arragement
belongs_to :photo
belongs_to _collage
end
```

The photo may change it size, which will cause the collage to change

Using the `touch: true`, doesn't work this way, because the chain isn't "one way up", as `arragement` points to `Photo` and `Collage`

How can I work this so a Photo change (ie touch) would also touch its Collages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an even shorter version:

```
class Photo
  has_many :arragements
  has_many :collages, through: :arragements

  after_save { collages.find_each(&:touch) }
end
```

Comment: This, while respecting the callback chain, does a separate UPDATE query for each collage, and since you anticipate for a lot of them (by using `find_each`), it may not be what you want to do. If @deefour's answer below that does `update_all` would suffice for your case, it's recommended over this one.

Answer (score 3):

You could just manually touch them all.

```
class Photo
  has_many :arragements
  has_many :collages, through: :arragements

  after_save do
    collages.update_all updated_at: Time.now
  end
end
```